# PHP Loop output to multiple HTML Blocks on the same page

Tags: php, html, joomla

Ok, first of all I dont know the proper terminology for what i'm trying to accomplish here. But it seems straight forward, just not easy.

I'm working on a joomla mod_article_news override, using the original for loop.
The problem is, i need to split the output in 2 different places, like:

```
<service_container>
    <services_carousel>
        <!-- PHP for loop starts here -->
            <service_block>
                Image and title
            <service_block>
        <!-- for loop ends here -->
    </services_carousel>

    <service_details>
        <details_list>
        <!-- I need the same For loop to output here at the same time -->
            <li>Intro text and Readmore button</li>
        </details_list>
    </service_details>
</service_container>
```

If you take a look, you can see I have the intro image and title in service_block, while the intro text and readmore button are in service_details.

The functionality here is basically intro image and title blocks, when user hovers over each block, the full-width container below will display the relevant intro text.

The original for loop looks like this:

```
<?php for ($i = 0, $n = count($list); $i < $n; $i ++) : ?>
    <?php $item = $list[$i]; ?>
```

If somebody can tell me the correct terminology for this, that would be great too! =)

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Did you actually tryied a loop on your code ? What was the output then ?

Comment: The loop works fine as it should, but only the part that is within the loop.
just the title and image. 

The intro text does not come out at all.

Comment: by the way...just so i dont seem like a complete idiot... yes, I realise thats correct. only whats inside the loop should actually loop.

My point is, I dont know a way to output the same loop in two separate blocks.

Comment: My advice is to try to display "by hand" 2 or more pack, and you will figure out where to put your loop.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean "by hand". The loop works, the code works, I just dont know how to split the output from the same loop.

I cant extend the loop to include both the title/image and intro/readmore, because they are housed in different HTML containers.

I added another loop to the intro/readmore, which works fine, except if I have the ordering set to "random" in joomla, the title and intro dont always match.